# Advanced graphics with GDI or GDI+

Tags: c++, .net, gdi+, gdi

I'm looking for some advanced tutorials or maybe open-source applications written in C++ or .NET that would implement a complex vector-based application, something like MS Visio or Autocad. What I need to know is how the guru of such applications are managing the rendering of complex objects (> 1000 rectangle) on mouse move, when user can move a complex object over other complex objects. I know about XOR painting and stuff, but if you check the above applications is clearly they are not using this technique. The whole object moves smoothly on top on another, not only its XOR reflection. Plus the moving objects show some additional info while moved, like current coordinates, or something else, so is not a static representation of it saved in a bitmap.

Any advises are welcome.

Thx

Comment: I have found double buffering to be very effective for avoiding flickering and smoothing things up when drawing

Comment: yes, I know about, and that's what I'm using (BufferedGraphics and its brothers), it works ok, but I see high CPU usage when moving the mouse, and I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: Did you find any solutions for those perf. problems at the end?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of graphical applications use some kind of [spatial partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) to prune down the number of objects they need to look at.  For example, if you move a rectangle, the application looks in a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) and finds the 2 or 3 other objects whose bounding boxes overlap the moving rectangle.  Then it only needs to do a full collision detection and graphics processing with 2 or 3 objects instead of 1000.

Comment: yes, that's when it comes about very huge objects in Autocad, in my case I have a complex trading chart, and I need to paint some complex figures using the mouse. I'm pretty sure such stuff is not used in MS Visio. Looking for applications that have something similar and have source code available to check.

Comment: here is a video of what I want to be done http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOkKf2Ixb-Q . That's an application where I test. It works ok, but when I move mouse and paint all that moving stuff it eats lots of CPU. This is the control I have http://pastebin.com/SF7k6KjC and here is the drawing http://pastebin.com/MQPGXm9u . Any ideas are welcome. If needed I can send the whole VS 2010 solution.